# How to detect and highlight if more than one word in a cell

Tags: excel, scripting, macros

I am trying to detect every cell in a row that has more than one word and than to highlight that cell so I can find them easier.

Is there a macro or something easier to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Spaces. Its just a list of customer names and companies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution:

Assuming your data starts in cell A2, put the following formula in cell B2

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))
```

This will put the count of spaces into column B.  You can then filter for rows that have 1 space, 2 spaces, 3 spaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the data.
2. Then go to `Conditional Formatting` > `Highlight Cells Rules` > `Text That
       Contains...` > and enter a space () in the popup box.

Comment: Thank you for the reply that works great if the name is just two words. The problem is if they have a middle initial like John J. Hopkins than there are more than one space.

Comment: Yes any string with more than one space.